# Comparison of 2 data sets with different sample sizes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, multiple-comparisons

I have two data sets that have different sample sizes and I am unsure on how to compare them. Dataset 1 has 51 participants but dataset 2 has only 20 participants.

The answers to the questions are expressed as percentages, the questions are mostly multiple choice with 4 options, but only results from the most positive answer is given and no other data is available. For example:

> Did you have a good day?
>   dataset 1 Yes 60% Maybe- No- 
>   dataset 2 Yes 40% Maybe- No-

I am aware I can't just say data set 1 was 20% more happy than data set 2 because the sample sizes are so different.

I want to know if there is a way / what is the best way to directly compare the two data sets given that the sample sizes are so different?

Comment: Compare them w/ respect to what? What would you like to be able to say about them after you have done whatever comparison?

Comment: Ok both data sets received the same questions but 6 months apart. What I would like to say is that changes I have made contributed to the high scores I got in my second data set despite the sample being much smaller. One my my questions was did Did you recive a written copy of the information discussed ? data set 1 yes was 30% and set 2 was 50% i want to try and equate that to the change I made. If this makes any sense.

Comment: Do you want to quantify the difference? Do you want to test if there was no difference?

Comment: I would like a way to quantify the difference please